# How to exclude term in .htaccess file using FilesMatch?

Tags: .htaccess

So I've been trying to set up a more specific .htaccess file for a few hours now and I just don't understand what's going on.

*Setup:* several php files for operation, we can simplify it to '**index.php**' and '**open.php**' and '**upload.php**'; then there are **uploaded files**, we don't know their names nor how many there will ever be.

*What I want:* There's two different users. Let's call them '**cUser**' and '**oUser**'. cUser is allowed to access any file. oUser is only allowed to access open.php and the uploaded files.

*What I did:* Here's my .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Download"
AuthUserFile /[...]/.htusers
```

followed by

```
<FilesMatch "[^(open\.php)]$">
Require user cUser
</FilesMatch>
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "!(open\.php)">
Require user cUser
</FilesMatch>
```

and many other different attempts. I expected to require cUser for any file other than oUser with what I did and wanted to go from there, but I never got it to work. What am I doing wrong? As soon as I added a '!' whereever no file needed authentification anymore and with the [^] expression it went wild and some files where accessible while others weren't, by no pattern that I would recognize. So how do I do a 'NOT' in a FilesMatch?

Comment: `<FilesMatch "(?!open\.php)$">`

Comment: No. If I use that every file needs cUser. Even open.php.

Comment: so, `oUser` is not allowed to access `index.php` and `upload.php` only?

Comment: yes, I guess you could put it like that

Comment: (Response to deleted answer) But that allows oUser to access index.php and upload.php. Which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: Sorry, feeling sleepy :| Will post an answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to add a new subdirectory for the uploaded files. This is the best way to handle uploaded files anyway, instead of loading them in the same directory as the php files. Now there's a htaccess file in the main directory:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Download"
AuthUserFile /[...]/.htusers
Require user cUser
<FilesMatch "open.php">
Require user cUser oUser
</FilesMatch>
```

and a second htaccess file in the directory for the uploads:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Download"
AuthUserFile /[...]/.htusers
Require user cUser oUser
```